Error: Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available when running react-native run-android
I am encountering an issue while trying to run my React Native application on Android using the command:
react-native run-android
The build fails with the following error:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. 
> Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available.

Steps taken to resolve the issue:

I have already run the react-native doctor command, and all issues flagged by the tool have been resolved successfully.
My Android SDK is configured correctly, and the environment variables (ANDROID_HOME, PATH) are properly set up.
Debugging the build configuration hasn't revealed any obvious problems with the Gradle setup.

Despite the above efforts, the issue persists.
